# How can we get rid of misspelled (typo) and unused (or "zombie") tags?

Tags: support, faq, tags

During the re-tagging of questions, tags sometimes become orphaned from existing questions.

Are these *zombie* tags ever removed from the [tags list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)?

What if a tag is misspelled and needs to be removed? How do we get rid of it?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.

Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in its destruction due to having no uses.

Comment: *Tags already cleared of all questions won't show up in the tags edit box when auto-completing, and are treated as if they don't exist yet*...not if the tag is clear but it isn't destroyed yet...

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: I removed that part for now; I don't have an account to test that with at the moment but I seemed to recall that users without enough reputation to *create* a tag cannot reuse tags with 0 posts associated, and thus won't see it when retagging a post.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I see the fresh tag *on-the-fly-tagging* being suggested when editing. BTW: [Why are new tags not deleted in the grace period?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278562/2932052)

Comment: @Wolf: but you have 1400-ish rep, which means that on *meta* you have the tag creation privilege (it's set to 500 points here). So since you can *create* the tag, the zombie tag isn't hidden. I'm trying to ascertain if it would be hidden if you did not have that privilege.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've found a tag to test with on SO, [let's see what happens...](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6398053)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The tag *benerator* is still suggested, when I editing. Should I wait until the grace period is over? ;-)

Comment: @Wolf: tag suggestions are almost certainly cached, so I'd wait a little. The tag page still exists. Note that the subsystem is *actually* called `benerator` and that's deliberate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it seems I did a mistake, this tag was used by purpose, it has a [tag wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27269780/revisions), so I'll check [another one...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assets-path)

Comment: @Wolf: I don't think that tag was needed in the first place; it wasn't a misspelling but I don't see the need to create that tag either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66269/discussion-between-wolf-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: News: Tags without tag wiki (see *assets-path*) seem not to be suggested!

Comment: Is this for SO or all SE sites? I didn't see anything about this in the recommended answer that popped up when I created a duplicate question about an empty tag.

Comment: This is for all SE sites; this FAQ posting was based of the [one on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags).