# FAQ Index for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, faq

## Community FAQ

**(For Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow)**

For official guidance from Stack Exchange, visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Stack Overflow is part of a wider network; for issues that apply to Stack Exchange sites in general, see the **[FAQ list on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)**.

---

### Asking & Answering

##### General

- [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572)
- [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

- [Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146)

- [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
- [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

- [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)
- [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362)
- [I want to seed Stack Overflow with questions about my product/project. What do I need to know?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421604)

##### Code Samples

- [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

- [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)
- [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537)

- [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

##### Scope/On-Topic

- ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think a question is not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252)

- [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

- [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849)

- [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374)

- [Is it okay to ask for code optimization help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286557)

- [Are htaccess questions ever on-topic at SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283033)
- [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Software Engineering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254570)
- [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254567)

##### Homework & Students

- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
- [Should I send students to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254433)
- [I've rethought my question about a homework assignment—why can't I get it deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403802)

##### Rate-Limits & Bans/Suspensions

- [If your question was not well received, read this before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262)
- [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542)
- [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)

---

### Editing/Formatting

- [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219)

- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)
- [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245)

- [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990)

- [Should I update very old answers when the solution becomes deprecated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288987)
- [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379)
- [How can I create a table in a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716)

---

### Tagging

- [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944)
- [How can we get rid of misspelled (typo) and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221)
- [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933)
- [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070)
- [How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318337)

---

### Reputation and Voting

- [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653)

- [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686)

- [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436)
- [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252270)

- [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487)

---

### User Interface and Configuration

- [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281740)
- [How do I hide the left navigation sidebar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369106)
- [How can I log out from Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254109)

---

### Moderation/Curation

##### General

- [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673)
- [How can I see close and reopen history of a question that wasn't edited?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334977)

##### Flags

- [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552)
- [What flags are automatically raised by the system?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317987)
- [Why was my custom flag declined? When should I use a custom flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368693)
- [Why was my moderator flag to have a duplicate question closed/reopened declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419708)

##### Closure

- [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476)

##### Review

- [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046)
- [How should I get started reviewing the Late Answers and First Questions/ Answers Queues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505)
- [How does the Triage review queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650)
- [Why was I suspended from reviewing for selecting "Requires Editing" in Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148)

#### Accounts

- [What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984)

#### Legal

- [What should I do about a clone service scraping Stack Exchange sites for content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253906)

---

### Meta Stack Overflow

- [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917)
- [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365)
- [Are questions about Stack Overflow for Teams on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow? Where can I get support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423394)

---

#### Looking for answers to a question not part of the FAQ?

First, look at questions tagged [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to see if there is a question not in this index that might have the answer you seek. If you still can't find an answer, then see the following instructions for proposing an FAQ question.

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ?

- Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body.
  The answer goes in an answer.
- **Link back** to this index by pasting this at the end of the question:

  `[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)`
- Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems
  to have hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a
  moderator.
- Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet
  community wiki should be made into a community wiki. This lowers the bar for editing (less reputation is required to be able to edit a community wiki post), and emphasizes the fact that it is a *community* FAQ by removing individual ownership of the post.
- After the post has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag added to it, add a link to it in
  the above [table of contents](/q/251225).

Comment: Should we copy-paste FAQ posts from MSE to here? I wanted to close a question here as dupe of an FAQ but it's only available on MSE ([link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)).

Comment: @Stijn: Yes, if a FAQ on MSE is a FAQ here too, feel free to follow the `faq-proposed` procedure.

Comment: Finding this page was a Herculean effort, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=FAQ  Where is the link that directly leads users to this page? If you search using the special faq [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+Stack+Overflow) then it's easier but if I'm a newcomer and don't think of the tag, where do I go?

Comment: @Mari-LouA the index isn’t directly linked, only the [meta-tag:faq] is, from the [What is Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) help page. Questions with the [meta-tag:faq] tag do link back to this page however.

Comment: Non knowing where else to post this, maybe this is the right place - could a FAQ be added that explains how to tag users? Also wondering if there's a direct message option. I think I figured out how to deal with spaces. Could you please confirm that spaces are always deleted, e.g. @MartijnPieters?

Comment: @markhogue: see the [help center article on commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), which links to [How do comment `@`replies work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)