# When exactly are tags created?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-wiki

I was reviewing a proposed tag-wiki edit for [ic-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5285012) and initially found the proposed edit sensible (a short description of the use of the tag).  Then I got curious of the exact nature of ic-ajax.

Looking into what ic-ajax actually is, I found it on [github](https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax) -- the project owner is a different person that the editor of the tag -- not sure if that matters.  The module looks minor and only about a few months old.

Then following up on StackOverflow I didn't see any questions tagged with the tag, although the tag info currently claims that there is "1 question".   Looking at other [meta Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) it looks like tag's are not created at-will unless you have a certain rep.  But I'm not able to determine who created the tag.  So, I assume that the creator have create a fake question, added the tag, then proposed a edit/create to the new tag-wiki, then deleted the fake question.

So my questions;

1. Is it acceptable behavior to create tags this way?
2. should this tag even exist?
3. when exactly are tags created? -- as the creation of the tag does not appear consistent with the [description given](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)
4. Is this a exploit bug, where new tags can be created by backdoor if they manage to suggest an edit to the wiki?

Comment: Tags are created when added to a question for the first time. Tags are cleaned up when they are no longer used on any question. I cleaned up this specific tag again (it is too minor to be useful).

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing no questions with that tag - [there is one question with ic-ajax as a tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709585/how-to-use-ic-ajax-with-jsonp)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate question -- I was not able to find anything specific to this observation.

Comment: @Soren: your question is very broad, there is also [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944) In this case: the tag is not useful.

Comment: @hichris123 -- I see that now, may just have been a caching delay.

Comment: @Soren: nevertheless, tag *was* still in use, is only no longer used now that I removed it, so dupe vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the tag again; it is too minor to be useful, one question about it does *not* warrant a tag (see [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944)).

The fact you found the tag page to be empty was simply due to caching; you found the tag early in its life.

You cannot create a tag by creating a tag wiki; tag wikis can only be created once a tag has been created. Tags are created by using them on questions.

In this case, because I removed the tag again, it'll be automatically cleaned up, including the tag wiki. See [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251221/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Comment: [It's baaaaaa-aaaaack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709585/how-to-use-ic-ajax-with-jsonp).