# New Tags: octal-number, octal-system, binary-system and binary-number - who accepted these new tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I found that [octal-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octal-number), [octal-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octal-system), [binary-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary-system) and [binary-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary-number) are four new tags since yesterday. There is already an [octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octal) and a [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary) tag.

- octal-*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469416/octal-numbers-underscore
- binary-*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704786/generate-3-bit-random-binary-number-every-clock-cycle-on-80c51-microcontroller

I thought Stack Overflow has a review system before creating new tags. How could these tags have been created without overview? Who can fix this?

If the community wants to have so many redundant tags, then please create aliases.

Comment: The tags have been added by someone with a higher rep: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27469416/revisions

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for the hint to the revision page, to see also tag modifications.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The tags were all added by one user with 8k+ reputation, enough for the [*create tags* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) at 1.5k. You only need to look at the post revisions to see it was not the original author of each post that added those tags.

There is no review process to add new tags; anyone with the privilege can create new ones. If the user still has < 2k their edits do go to the edit review queue like any other edit. You can track new tags on the [*new tags* page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), there are many who do watch the page for any 'weird' or redundant new tags. Tag creations are easily cleaned up (just like any other edit), and if a tag has been burninated (removed from all posts) they get [deleted automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251221/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags).

The tags add nothing over the existing [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary) and [octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octal) tags; I've removed them again.

The user in question also copied Wikipedia content wholesale into the tag wikis (for [octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octal), [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary) and [hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hex)), which I have cleaned up now (mostly by reverting). Tag wiki content *does* require review until you have the [*trusted user* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), but reviewers failed to do their work and did not check for copied content. The tag wikis were way too extensive, tag wikis should explain how the tags should be used, not be encyclopaedic entries on the subject.

Comment: I know the create privilege at 1.5k. So there is no review process for new tags? How does SO control the proliferation of new tags?

Comment: @Paebbels: people keep an eye on the [new tags page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) and generally just clean up if something is misapplied.

Comment: "but reviewers failed to do their work and did not check for copied content" [time to implement this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238339/213575)

Comment: I'm wondering why you didn't simply revert the edit: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27469416/revisions Are there penalties when edits are reverted? Or is it simply faster because of UI design?

Comment: @ArtjomB. It was easier just to use the keyboard shortcuts to delete the two tags. Reverting requires clicking with a mouse.