# Kill the [8.1] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I was browsing the [new tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), when I spotted the [8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/8.1) tag, of which the former was created sometime yesterday (apparently).

The tag itself is ambiguous as it could refer to *anything* named/versioned `8.1` such as *Windows 8.1*.
The tag also has no wiki:

[image]

*As well as this the tag has no questions, so **why was the tag created in the first place?***

It's not obvious what the tag is for, or what it refers to. The creator of the tag also didn't help by leaving the tag summary and wiki blank.

The tag is useless and should be removed.

As the tag is new, [I'm unsure whether it'll be caught in the destruction script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251221/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags), therefore I'm posting the request here.

Comment: @ProgramFOX See the last sentence. My question *requests the removal of the tag*, and doesn't ask *how do we remove it?*, therefore the question isn't really a duplicate. I'm unsure how the destruction script works, will it pick up the newly created tag and remove it, or will it ignore the tag as it's new?

Comment: It does not matter whether the tag is new or not, it will still be automatically burned.