# Couldn't edit [code-challenge] tag into a post. What gives?

Tags: support, tags

When I tried to add the **existing** tag [code-challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475851/not-able-to-understand-crypto4-on-sphere-online-judge-especially-the-test-cases) to make it easier to find, the system mumbled something about tag creation requiring a certain minimum reputation. Good thing, too, since tag *creation* was not what I intended.

What's going on? If that tag is in a limbo state where it shouldn't be used, why not delete it and be done?

I also noticed that the tag had no description, which makes it anybody's guess whether it is for posing code challenges or for asking about them...

Comment: I could... but I wouldn't. Can you find questions with the tag, that I couldn't.

Comment: Sounds like a meta-tag to me. It might be blacklisted.

Comment: There are no questions with this tag. It was probably created by someone, and then subsequently *removed* from that question by an edit. Thus, the tag [is kind of in limbo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251221/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags), waiting to be purged from the system because it is no longer being used. I don't know how you found the tag; it is not suggested in the tag editor popup window.

Comment: What you *should* have been doing is voting to close an off topic question, rather than trying to add a tag which would be used on other off-topic questions.

Comment: @Braiam: I can see that you succeeded, thanks. But I'm still interested in knowing the whys and wherefores... @ Cody: I found it via the "edit favourites" thing a while ago.

Comment: Edit favourites? What is that?

Comment: That tag is a synonym for `[challenge]`, which currently decorates zero questions. It being a synonym *may* explain why you were able to choose it. I personally believe that tag became obsolete since [codegolf.se] entered beta.

Comment: @Cody: "Favorite Tags [edit]" on the right-hand side in the question list

Comment: How will the code-golfers react if someone starts asking about code challenges (puzzles)? Should posts like the one in question be moved over to the golf course?

Comment: @DarthGizka No, it should not be migrated to PPCG. PPCG is for posing and answering challenges, not for assistance in solving off-site challenges. The question is on-topic on SO. However, the question cannot be understood without the link to SPOJ, so it's a poorly asked question.

Comment: Just tried this, but [tag:code-challenge] doesn't show up in autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of the information from the comment discussion so far:

- [code-challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) is not a real tag; it exists only as synonym for [challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/challenge)
- synonyms can be picked when editing one's favourite tags but not (?) in the tag list of a question *(that's why adding the tag to the question was interpreted as intended creation)*
- the question was about an off-site code challenge, not posing one for everyone's edification; hence it was on topic for Stack Overflow and off-topic for  [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)
  *(see [We're not a Q&A site. But what should be done about it?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/were-not-a-qa-site-but-what-should-be-done-about-it?cb=1))*