# Why is a tag named 'fuckit' allowed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags

There is a tag named [fuckit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuckit) on SO, wondering how such tags are allowed?

Comment: Wondering why you think it shouldn't be allowed? There's also [brainfuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck).

Comment: I don't think it shouldn't be allowed and I've asked a leading question to assume that I think it shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding your last comment. Your question is _"How/Why is such a tag allowed"_, and my counter-question is: _"Why shouldn't it be?"_. Please be explicit in why you wonder why this tag should or shouldn't be allowed. Is it merely because of the word "fuck"?

Comment: Also see [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221); there already are no posts tagged with it.

Comment: @CodeCaster That seems like the obvious reason it would be objected to...

Comment: @Tim no, that doesn't seem obvious to me, hence my question for the OP to be specific. I want to know the rationale, before deciding whether we should take action, as to not overreact or otherwise do the wrong thing. If the rationale is _"We shouldn't allow naughty words on the site"_ that's fine, but that should explicitly be mentioned. Current phrasing is too vague.

Comment: I'm against swearing, but it could be a badly named library too... Like: Function Utility Component kit.

Comment: I will counter with, who cares, it's just a word. You're an adult, you're on the internet, you'll be fine.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking"? Come on meta people, the question got an accepted answer from a dev in a few minutes.

Comment: @Ben apart from _"there isn't really much to be done here"_, the answer of Oded states _"Unused tags will be automatically removed"_, which does not seem to be an answer to the question that is asked (despite it being accepted). The OP didn't bother to respond to my comments that multiple people upvoted, so I and others with me feel that it is unclear what the OP actually is asking.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't have an attitude towards  "Why shouldn't it be allowed?" or "Why it should be allowed?", rather I'm uncertain about it and will not make it explicit.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the feedback. I'm sorry but then as far as I'm concerned, this question stays closed as "Unclear what you're asking", because you could ask the same for _any_ tag. Perhaps you meant to ask: _"Are there any rules for what words can and can't be used in tag names?"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster, you are right, I respect individuals choices.

Comment: @Abbas but that's the thing. If you don't explain WHY it shouldn't be allowed, then you won't have much traction. Honestly I care 0% about harsh language (I swear like a sailor), and if you think that it shouldn't be allowed because it says fuck... then think about the logic.... if the library IS called fuckit (or brainfuck), then why would you NOT allow the tag?

Comment: @Patrice I did not say it should be allowed or not allowed.

Comment: @Abbas It's an assumption of the statement, "How is X allowed?" that you feel X isn't acceptable.  If you honestly have no opinion on whether or not it's acceptable then you should have phrased the question differently.  (And of course if you had no reason to feel it wasn't acceptable there'd be no reason to ask a question about it in the first place.)

Comment: @servy Please look at the question as it is and  make no assumptions and add additional meanings to it by passing it through if this than that.

Comment: @Abbas So you just see random tags that seem entirely appropriate and as on meta how people have allowed that tag to exist?

Comment: I think I'll go ask why we have a Python tag....

Comment: So then @Abbas, if youask how are such tags allowed, and can't say why they SHOULDN'T be allowed, this question is pointless.....

Comment: Because two tears in a bucket?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a [library for JavaScript](https://github.com/mattdiamond/fuckitjs) named fuckit, which has also been [ported to Python](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy). The JavaScript version removes lines of code that cause errors until there are no errors left.

> FuckItJS uses state-of-the-art technology to make sure your javascript code runs whether your compiler likes it or not.
>
> Through a process known as Eval-Rinse-Reload-And-Repeat, FuckItJS repeatedly compiles your code, detecting errors and slicing those lines out of the script. To survive such a violent process, FuckItJS reloads itself after each iteration, allowing the onerror handler to catch every single error in your terribly written code.

And the Python version works as several different python types:

> FuckIt.py uses a combination of dynamic compilation, Abstract Syntax Tree rewriting, live call stack modification, and love to get rid of all those pesky errors that make programming so hard.
>
> - As a replacement for import
> - As a decorator
> - As a context manager

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: Well that explains its name, anyway.

Comment: This is incredible. If only it did the opposite, then it would be perfect for making MVCEs. `:)`

Answer (score 37):

There are no questions tagged with it - it will be removed from the system automatically (a job runs daily to remove such zombie tags).

Someone with tag creation privileges probably added that tag to a question and it got removed from it.

Frankly, with user moderation and the fact that *there is no question with the tag*, there isn't really much to be done here. There is no point in preventing it (as people who really want to mess around will find a way to mess around).

Comment: @MilanvanDijck Why is that different from a library name?