# What are tags without questions? with existing synonym

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I found tags as [weblogic-11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weblogic-11g) and [weblogic-8.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weblogic-8.x) that exists in the tag list, but there are no questions and no wiki or information as [weblogic-10.x/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/weblogic-10.x/info). Should these tags be removed? If not, why isn't there's any information page?

I found [weblogic11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weblogic11g), but weblogic-11g isn't a synonym of it.

After 24 hours the synonyms haven't been removed as you might expect based on [How can we get rid of misspelled (typo) and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251221/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-typo-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Might be because there are still existing synonym pointing to them, e.g. weblogic-8 is a synonym to  weblogic-8.x

Comment: Either they have been turned into synonyms of other tags or (correct me if I'm wrong) they have been burniated but not deleted.

Comment: I assume these tags will just get cleaned up. You haven't observed them being present for 24 hours, right?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth tags are still available after 24 Hours

Comment: Oh, I've looked further, it looks like the tags are deleted but there are active synonyms to the tags. If you look at the tag list, you won't find [tag:weblogic-8.x] on there, but you will find [tag:weblogic-8] which is a synonym to [tag:weblogic-8.x] as can be seen on the [synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). I've cast a reopen vote, but reposting with this info in the question might be more appropriate

Comment: @user7294900 I've raised the more general issue of orphaned tag synonyms [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317928/auto-delete-orphaned-tag-synonyms), apparently there are a lot more tags that suffer from this issue.