# How can I get this tag renamed that I just created?

Tags: support, tags

By tagging my [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53668416/3441504) with [vaadin-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin-12) I created a new tag because there was no question yet for [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) 12 which has been released December 2018. But after creating the tag, I saw that for the previous Vaadin versions, the tag naming convention was without the hyphen, so I would like to rename the tag [vaadin-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin-12) to [vaadin12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin12), so the tags are named consistently. But I don't have the rights to do so.

Can someone with enough rep kindly help me with that?

Comment: The tag you created is actually the preferred variant, with a `-` between the name and the version. So imho don't bother with renaming the tag.

Comment: While I agree, I think having the same naming convention as the previous versions is more important. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 31):

You can just remove the tag, and add the correct one. Tags with 0 questions will automatically get deleted.

No need for anyone to help.

See [How can we get rid of misspelled (typo) and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221/7296893)

Comment: You need to wait for the tag cleanup script after deleting the current tag, because they are too similar.

Comment: @Stijn yes that was my issue. How long can it take for the tag cleanup script to run?

Comment: @Cashbee it runs once per day. I want to say around 03:00 UTC, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @stijn The page that Erik linked to states the same time ;)