# You are attempting to create tag [google-cloud-robotics] but [googlecloudrobotics] exists

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I mis-typed it without dashes first. All the docs we upload link to the tag with dashes. Can we register both linking them to the same tag? Or how should we proceed? To be clear, I'd like to use [google-cloud-robotics], but created [googlecloudrobotics] by accident first.

Comment: Just make sure to remove that wrong tag from all questions, wait a day for it to get deleted, and then create the appropriate tag. See [How can we get rid of misspelled (typo) and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221/7296893)

Comment: I renamed the tag.