# What happened to the sierrachart tag I created?

Tags: support, tags

About a week or two ago, I added a new tag (**sierrachart**) that I was hoping to help sort out and find code questions related to C-style programming for the trading platform, *SierraChart*. The tag disappeared and I was never informed in any visible way to what happened or why it was not accepted. I find this kind of treatment quite offending and very counter productive when trying to engage myself in cleaning up, helping and maintaining SO.

Can someone please explain what happened?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You created the [sierrachart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sierrachart) tag by adding it to three questions:

- [Sierra Chart DTC Java Socket Connection null terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670927/sierra-chart-dtc-java-socket-connection-null-terminator)
- [How to run only one if statement and ignore the other inside C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851881/how-to-run-only-one-if-statement-and-ignore-the-other-inside-c-function)
- [Linker outfile property file does not match targetpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700081/linker-outfile-property-file-does-not-match-targetpath)

The tag was subsequently removed from those three questions by another user, which allowed the unused tag to be [automatically removed from the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251222).

I do not see any reason for having the tag on any of those three questions. None of them had anything specific to do with the SierraChart library. The asker just *happened* to be using that library. They could just as well have had the same problems with any other library.

While I can understand your *confusion* over what happened to a tag that you recently created, I think it's a gross exaggeration to say that this is in any way "offensive".

Comment: Thanks Cody. That make sense. Maybe not *grossly* but slightly. After all it did take me some effort to markup, link and adjust the (tag) text to be as clear and useful as possible, so when *something* causes that to just dissappear without explanation, that feel quite offensive.

Comment: @not2qubit - Stop taking an **automatic tag cleanup** personally. An unnecessary unused tag was automatically cleaned up.

Comment: @SecurityHound I am not taking it personally, I was simply not aware that it existed! In addition, it would not have been automatically deleted if someone had not removed the tags, or if there had been a notification that this was actually done. Maybe we need to add a status notification for created tags?