# Throw out the [in] tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Stack Overflow has an [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in) tag, without any questions to its name. I understand that [unused "zombie" tags are removed by an automatic process that runs at 03:00 UTC every day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221), but the [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in) tag has persisted for at least several days without getting removed.

Oddly, I noticed that the tag page (and the Stack Exchange API) [seems to think that this tag contains 1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/in/topusers). Clearly, though, there are no questions to be displayed in the tag list. I also confirmed with a moderator that there are not even any *deleted* questions having this tag.

Why has the [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in) tag persisted so long with a phantom question associated with it? What button needs to be pushed to get it completely removed?

I've also noticed another tag with the same characteristic, the [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i) tag, which has no description, no visible questions (although the questions counter is 1) and it exists for several days.

Comment: This is probably the same issue we discovered a while back with indexing showing incorrect question count (even for moderators and staff) for some tags despite the question list showing the right number of questions. It's only noticeable when there are very few (or no) questions in the tag, and only an issue when it prevents a tag from getting auto-deleted. At some point in the last month or two the indexing process got a little borked and has stopped updating things correctly in these cases. Not sure what the status of the internal bug report is. This is definitely a bug, though.

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful info? Today I see it on the new tags view, page 10. These tags were created at the same time: [tag:i], [tag:home], [tag:in], [tag:a], [tag:few], [tag:minutes], [tag:ill], [tag:you], [tag:know], and [tag:when]. I suspect someone tried to abuse the tag system to make a sentence like "I (get) home in a few minutes, I'll (let) you know when." Since `get` and `let` are valid tags, they don't show up.

Comment: @TylerH do we know that they are not deleted in the backend and only in the index?

Comment: Let me answer myself, apparently [in is not allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0xHD.png). I don't get the new tags warning, but it's not allowed, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: As was pointed out to me in chat, sometimes [this can be due to locked and deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bterm%5D+is%3Alocked&searchOn=3) that still have the tag. But there are no locked questions showing for [in]

Comment: I'm surprised to see the `[in]` tag does not stand for `intelligent network`.

Comment: This can happen when a draft Collective article is tagged with [in]. I created a draft article tagged [tag:a-draft-article-keeps-this-tag] and that tag behaves similarly to [tag:in]. (although the Q count is 0 instead of 1)

Comment: @Smitop: Looking at the Tags page right now, it lists that tag as having "1 question" now (despite it obviously not being on any questions).

Comment: @V2Blast Yep, it appears that the question count difference was a caching thing. I'm pretty sure [in] is on a draft collective article. Hopefully this can get fixed along with [this other collective article tag issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418785/10113238).

Comment: According to JNAT, the bug is being investigated now:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419767/85661

Answer (score 7):

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles, including [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i)) has now been cleaned up.

As indicated in the comments, this was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted about 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.

Thank you all for your patience!