# ​[how-to] burninate this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

Seriously? We have a [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/how-to) tag? Well... we shouldn't. Let's go through the criteria:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   Absolutely not. Other than that the OP wants to know how to do something, no. And that is implied given that they're asking a question.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Sometimes... figuring out how to do something *can* be on topic, for example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82831/16886597), that's fine. But this could totally be another [plzsendtehcodez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plzsendtehcodez) (albeit, less rude).
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Certainly not.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   I guess? They want to know how to do something... still useless as a tag though.

It only has three questions, so getting rid of it shouldn't be hard.

---

For anyone asking about the zero-width space at the start of the title, it is to avoid the "Title contains a [tag] prefix; please use the tag field to enter tags instead" message so I can have the pun

Comment: It has 3 questions... Do we need a burninate request?

Comment: I find it amusing that one of the three questions is actually a meta question.

Comment: @Catija Yes, I've flagged it in hopes it can be migrated here. SurajRao: I have under 2k rep and the edit queue is full, so might as well go to Meta if someone else has to do it

Comment: It's done. Removed it from the two questions where it was not appropriate at all. The third one was migrated.

Comment: This tag has surfaced before as well. Might be time to outright blacklist it. /cc @Catija (in case you can do so while you're here)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine It's a bit more complicated because I don't have access to the tools for blocking tags since it's a dev-only thing. If you throw the block request tag and status-review on this I can get it moving through the process, though. It's something I need to document anyway. If y'all can figure out what warning text you would want to appear, that'd help me out a ton.

Comment: Bonus: it's a stuck tag (see [Throw out the \[in\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417362/throw-out-the-in-tag) for context)

Comment: @Catija I don't have anything super concrete, but maybe something in the lines of "`Tags are not meant to describe what type of question you have. Instead, use tags to [describe the content of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) [potentially something about "by using relevant tags", though not necessary]`"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Original response:

The [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/how-to) tag is now blocked on Stack Overflow. Anyone attempting to add the [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/how-to) tag to their question will be shown the following message:

> The 'how-to' tag is not allowed.
>
> Tags should [describe the content of your question](/help/tagging), not what type of question you have or why you're asking it. If you need to provide additional details, include them in the body of your post instead.

(The first line of the above is the default message shown for all blocked tags; the rest of it is based on Zoe's initial suggestion in the comments of your post, with some edits.)

---

### Update:

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles) has now been cleaned up again.

This was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted about 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.