# Collectives articles can be tagged with blocklisted tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, articles, tag-blocklist

Collectives™ Articles™ can have tags, but aren't subject to the usual restrictions: they can have any number of tags, and can bypass the tag blocklist. As such, it's possible to stop tags with no associated questions from being deleted by creating a draft Article with those tags. It's even possible to use `and` and `or` as tags, which gets some really weird treatment by the tag system (they don't get displayed right in the tag editor, and their question list pages don't work, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VvSO.png))

Example ([link for those who can see (deleted) draft articles](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go/articles/edit/71632829)):

[image: a draft article tagged: go, untagged, example, blahrsntirst, homework]

When editing the tag list, it does show an error about this, but you can save despite it:

[image: a list of tag errors]

Comment: *"link for those who can see (deleted) draft articles"* Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to include even moderators, so I suspect that link is less useful than one might hope.

Comment: Seems to be limited to drafts. No repro when editing a live article

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner.  We filed this bug on our internal backlog but forgot to update the meta post. Note that, due to the limit of 5 tags on a post, I had to remove the `tags` tag in order to add the `status-planned` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. We are now enforcing reputation requirements to create new tags on articles. We have also added validation that should prevent blocklisted or additional tags from saving.