# Let's say bye bye to [hello]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, blocklist-request

There is a [hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello) with no questions in it if you go to [the "Newest" tab for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello?tab=Newest):

[image: The tag "hello" shows no questions under the "Newest" tab.]

But also hovering over the tag on the same page shows it has one question:

[image: On hover, the tag info says there is 1 question for "hello".]

This is a known issue - the tag is stuck.

There is no value for having such a generic tag name, hence I propose it gets blocked.

For the error message, I propose:

> The word "hello" is too generic. If it is a library, or a feature of another technology, be more specific. For example, [hello.js] or [windows-hello].

Comment: Adding tags to the blocklist is only done if the tag is first burninated and *then is recreated*. Has that happened? It doesn't look like that process has taken place. The blocklist isn't a solution to the bug that causes a tag to not appear as deleted once it doesn't have any non-deleted questions and the UTC time passes when the tag is marked as "nonexistent". [That's in quotes, because the tags aren't actually deleted from the system, they are just displayed that way. Moderators can still search for deleted questions with the tag.]

Comment: The blacklist _is_ the solution. I explicitly asked for blacklist requests on these tags. The company isn't fixing the bug, but some of these tags continue being highly problematic, and need to disappear

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine That's not a good solution to this problem. Every one of these that I've seen is fairly easily resolved by just re-deleting the question which is causing the tag to be stuck. Normally, it's just going through and finding the question that was relatively recently deleted which is causing the tag to to be stuck and re-deleting it. In the case of this tag, there are only 9 deleted questions for the entire tag. It's fairly trivial to just re-delete every single one of those.

Comment: @Makyen Tags are stuck because of draft articles, not because of questions. We _cannot_ touch those, even if we tried.

Comment: @VLAZ At what URL are you seeing the "1 question"? I'm not able to reproduce that at any of the URLs where that is normally displayed. I'd like to be able to reproduce it prior to doing anything in order to know that it's resolved by re-deleting the questions.

Comment: Synonyms: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hello/synonyms -- also when you hover the tag.

Comment: Also, initial bug report on the problem outlining the behavior (but not the actual cause, that was mentioned elsewhere): [Throw out the \[in\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417362/6296561)

Comment: @Makyen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello?tab=Newest if I hover over the tag.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Then the solution is to have SE handle the specific issue on the draft article. The solution isn't to burden *every single action on the site made over the rest of time* that checks for the validity of tags with yet another blocklisted item in order to fix something that *isn't actually a blocklist issue*.

Comment: @Makyen Why, yes, and we've been down that path. It's been nearly 4 months since the problem was identified and placed at the very bottom of the backlog, while the tags continue causing problems. Blacklisting is the last resort because they're _not dealing with the actual problem_, and aren't going to for the near foreseeable future.

Comment: @Makyen It also shows "1 question" searching for the hello tag on the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnajt.png))

Comment: Also, that was after I nudged CMs for around 2 months just to get it into the backlog at all. Unless you have a way to magically get SE to prioritise gaping problems in site moderation (this and the stacks editor being two of the many major problems at the moment), blacklisting the problematic tags, specifically the recurring ones, is the only option. As an aside, nudging the dev team a sufficient amount of times is actually a strategy for making the solution to the problem a priority

Comment: This tag, which has a *grand total of **9** questions*, doesn't really seem like it's a "gaping problems in site moderation". Yes, it's annoying, but "gaping problem"??? sufficient to add a burden to *every single check to validate tags*???

Comment: Sufficiently obscure tags tend to have new questions removed relatively immediately. There's also far more problematic tags than this one; there are 34 known stuck tags as of July or August (using a dumb metric that misses all tags with questions, however, so more than these do exist, but they're not easy to detect), including the gem [tag:interview], which has been refusing to die and continues attracting blatant garbage

Comment: Here's the complete known list (without formatting because arsed), if you're interested: 
abdullah
sezer-01-00hotmail.com
sqlmode
goo
travel-tim
protect-master
master-push
ill
you
know
i
in
a
few
status-check
hello
cooking
how-to
machine-learnin
dlworkbench
do
ubey
danismanl
dani
manlik
career-development
interview
freshers
udyachts
yachtrentalcompany
yachtrentals
a-draft-article-keeps-this-tag
ballerina-openapi-tool
btc

Comment: Then it sounds like [tag:interview] is an excellent tag to watch in order to close off-topic questions, which people are *going to post anyway*, regardless of the existence of the tag. I'm not saying that this issue isn't annoying, or that it shouldn't be fixed. It's just that adding to the blocklist isn't the right solution, at least not as a generalized solution for every such tag that gets stuck.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine For the ones which are *very* low volume and *clearly* have no conceivable use on SO, why don't we just merge them all into a single, obviously inappropriate tag that's already blocked? Note: I'm saying *not* do that for tags like [tag:career-development], which has 20,776 questions, but do do it for tags like [tag:udyachts], [tag:yachtrentalcompany], and [tag:yachtrentals], which all have 0 questions?

Comment: Last time I tried that, I got an error message. I just tried on [yachtrentalcompany], and the last "question" is gone, but I still got an error message ("an unknown error has occurred"), and the merge dialog still seems to think there's a question to retag

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I'd like to take a look at what's in the console when that happens (i.e. I'd like to do one, so I can see what's happening). Into which tag are you merging them?

Comment: Went with [exclude]. It  got blacklisted recently. I did check the console, but just got the generic error message there too

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I went with [tag:idea], which has been blocklisted basically forever and had no questions in it. I didn't get an error when I merged [tag:udyachts] into it, but now the [tag:idea] does exist with a single question, but it is blocklisted. I'm undecided as to which merge target would be better. I'd probably pick to use [tag:idea] as the merge target, as it can end up as a separate list of just these where there's a problem, so the devs, when they get to it, don't have to go searching.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I've applied the solution I mention in my answer to all the tags you listed above (all which hadn't already been merged into something else) with the exception of [tag:btc]. For [tag:btc], it seemed its existence was arguable, so I was uncomfortable editing it out of all existing non-deleted questions. However, I did move the single post/article/draft/whatever which was causing the tag to stick into [tag:stuck-tag-newbie-btc], so if the [tag:btc] tag is burninated, then the system will handle [tag:btc] normally by "deleting" it with the UTC-based daily tag cleaning.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine you can add the tags [tag:pro] and [tag:x] to the list. These pop up frequently too, got them on a watch list.

Comment: @Makyen could you please apply your solution to the two above mentioned tags as well. TIA

Comment: You'll regret blocking [hello] next time your "Hello, World!" program fails.

Comment: @kjhughes But, there's also the deleted tag [tag:hello-world] (332 deleted questions), which would be more appropriate. There's also the deleted tag [tag:helloworld] (3 deleted questions). [In case it's not clear, this is sarcasm. Please don't use any of these tags.]

Comment: Can we please have a separate StackOverflow for these completely uninteresting tag deletions that doesn't show up in the goddam sidebar all the time?

Comment: @Noumenon no, we can't.

Comment: Maybe the tag can be blacklisted just to make the devs prioritize this issue to tacke the performance issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles) has now been cleaned up.

As I indicated in an earlier comment, this was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.

I've followed up with the site moderators, and confirmed that this tag block request is no longer necessary now that the underlying problem has been addressed. As such, I've retagged the request as  [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Thank you all for your patience!

Answer (score 23):

#### The solution tried below appears to *not* be effective (or only effective for a maximum of 24 hours)

After letting some time pass (< 24 hours) and leaving the system to do its thing, it looks like we're back to the previous state for all of the tags which were changed. The reversion to the state as it was prior to the merger described below affected the [hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello), and all the other mergers I [mention in a comment on the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421664/lets-say-bye-bye-to-hello/421666?noredirect=1#comment935527_421664) of the list of tags provided by Zoe stands with Ukraine [in a comment on the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421664/lets-say-bye-bye-to-hello/421666?noredirect=1#comment935511_421664).

Given that all of the tags similarly ended up back in their starting state, the most likely occurrence is that the merger operation didn't *actually* change the tag on whatever post or draft it exists on to cause the tag to be stuck. Then, when the UTC time based script was run which marks unused tags as "deleted", the system realized that the original tags did, in fact, exist, so unmarked them as "deleted" and that the changed tag name did not actually exist, so deleted it. Another two possibilities are that the system reverted all the changes (substantially less likely than not having actually made the change in the first place), or that someone manually reverted all of the tag changes (possible, but very unlikely without there being the intent to do so and having all the affected questions/article drafts/whatever under the control of one person or a very small number of people).

To test it again, I've merged [hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello) into [banned-tag-dont-use-hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/banned-tag-dont-use-hello), which should communicate to a human, in the very unlikely case that it was a user who changed it back.

#### Attempted solution

After some discussion and a bit of experimenting, it looks like moderators can handle the issue of such stuck tags, at least to get them gone from general use until SE actually fixes the problem.

I merged [hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello) into [stuck-tag-newbie-hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stuck-tag-newbie-hello) (which is already blocklisted, because "newbie" isn't permitted in tags). The effect of the merge was that *only the single non-deleted post*, which was just the one question/article/draft/whatever which was causing [hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello) to be stuck, was merged into the new tag. All of the existing deleted posts with [hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello) were *not* merged into the new [stuck-tag-newbie-hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stuck-tag-newbie-hello). So, merging such "stuck" tags into similar, per-tag "stuck-tag-newbie-<tagname>" holding tags appears to be a viable method of resolving the issue of a "problem" stuck tag. It moves the "stuck" post into the holding tag where SE can deal with it whenever they get around to it, while preserving the information of the original name of the stuck tag and the history of any deleted questions which still use the tag.

This is, of course, *not* a solution for tags which we want blocklisted for "normal" reasons (i.e. recreated after a burnination).

Comment: _This is, of course, not a solution for for tags which we want blocklisted for "normal" reasons (i.e. recreated after a burnination)._ Why not? If SE fails to implement a proper blocklist that mods can access and has little performance consequences, and this meets that need exactly, why not use it? We can always undo and blocklist as soon as SE's method of blocklisting isn't a huge regex loaded always

Comment: @ErikA It's not a solution for normal blocklisting, because it doesn't *actually* blocklist the original tag. It puts the system state to the point where the tag has been burninated (i.e. there are no longer any non-deleted questions with the tag) and the tag "deleted". That doesn't prevent someone with the tag creation privilege from recreating the tag. The intent behind a "normal" blocklist request is to prevent the tag from ever being added to a question. This doesn't do that, so can't be used when that's the real goal. That's not the real goal of this question.

Comment: This solves the problem of having a "stuck" tag that's accumulating inappropriate questions *because the tag already exists and anyone can add it to a question*. The normal process for handling "removal" of a tag is that the tag is burninated (removed from all non-deleted questions and/or questions with the tag are closed and deleted). The system then puts the tag in a "deleted" state, requiring the tag creation privilege to add it to a new question. A tag being "stuck" prevents the system from thinking the tag is "deleted", so there's no reputation requirement for adding it to a question.

Comment: SE reserves blocklisting for tags which have been burninated (at least once), but then recreated. From the system's point of view, blockliting is *expensive*, so it's reserved for things that *really need* it. The general assumption is that once a tag's been burninated that it won't be recreated, because it should be obvious to *most* people with the tag creation privilege that the tag shouldn't exist. That works most of the time. Blocklisting is for when a tag keeps being recreated. That's not this situation. This solution allows a tag to get past a "stuck" point in the "normal" process.

Comment: I get that, but the current system of waiting for a problem to occur at least twice before doing something about it is suboptimal, and I can't think of a reason why blocklisting should be expensive, even though it currently is. The current implementation of the blocklist being a regex sent with every question is weird, afaict there's no reason checking if a tag exists in a huge list of existing tags should be way less expensive than checking if a tag exists in a short list of blocked tags.

Comment: The assumption that burninated tags won't reappear since it's obvious (wasn't obvious when they were created in the first place, and it wasn't obvious to the people using the tag many times too) or because people will read meta and see that it's been burninated before (people reading meta, imagine that) is strange. If I have a bit of spare time I might try making an overview of recreation of burninate tags, I expect it to be fairly high, but can't get it out of SEDE afaict. The solution here is to make blocklisting inexpensive, and this trick seems to come close.

Comment: @ErikA This trick doesn't come even remotely close to making a tag actually blocklisted. It doesn't actually change the state of blocklisting for the affected tag. It *just* moves the "stuck" thing to somewhere where it's not causing a problem that's as significant.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I should do my research on how often burninated tags recur, and perhaps write a feature request if it's a real problem

Comment: @ErikA Just to be clear, I'm not saying that how this works is anywhere close to optimal. There's substantial room for improvement. Unfortunately, without development access, it's really not possible to say where the real pain points are in the design. In general, yes, it commonly takes longer to compile and run a regex than a quick database query, but there are trade-offs and optimizations for most things. Having the capability of at least some of the blocklist entries using regular expressions is necessary. That doesn't mean all of them need to or that the performance couldn't be improved.

Comment: (Spell checkers need to be "taught" *[blocklist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blocklist)* and Wiktionary the word as a verb.)