# Change tag 'tanstackreact-table' to 'tanstack-react-table'

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

The former one is generated from `@tanstack/react-table`, and is not very good

Answer (score 0):

The tag [tanstackreact-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tanstackreact-table) existed on exactly [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72702096) which you posted about. This means you also created the tag at the same time.

[Tags can be created by any user with at least 1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). The only way to create a tag is to add it to a question. Conversely, to delete a tag, it needs to be removed from all questions: [Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251222).

I have [made an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72702096/revisions#rev-body-411fd381-0764-4c86-8189-1e4305271bb5) and swapped [tanstackreact-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tanstackreact-table) for [react-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-table) which seems the correct tag for this. The tag wiki says the official website is https://react-table.tanstack.com/

If it is indeed different, then you are free to create a new tag again. It would be advisable to edit the tag information and add usage guidance and a wiki, so it is easier for others to use the tag correctly in the future.